# Why does xor truncate number values?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, bit-manipulation

Or... how do you XOR doubles without getting integer results?

I am using Actionscript 3.0 and found the following:

```
var a:Number = 3.000000004;
var b:Number = 29.999999999;
trace ("a: " + a); //3.000000004
trace ("b: " + b); //29.999999999
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
trace ("a: " + a); //29
trace ("b: " + b); //3
```

Clearly, the XOR operation is converting my Numbers into ints.  I am a bit surprised by this and don't exactly understand the reason behind it.  But I do know that other bitwise operations will also change Number into int, so I am not *that* surprised.

Be that as it may, is there a way to XOR doubles (aka Numbers) without having them get truncated to integers?  I used the above XOR originally for performance optimization (these number switches are executed millions of times in an array).  I assumed if I skipped the temporary variable, I would see a speed increase.   Alas, if the Number data gets changed to int, it is all for naught.

Just wondering if there is a solution to this or if I need to give up on XOR in this case.

(ps, I won't be able to check this thread for a while, but appreciate any suggestions, knowledge, etc. in the meantime)

(pps, in case you are curious, this is the method I am trying to speed up if possible)

```
public static function reversePairs(values:Vector.<Number>):void {
    //1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2
    var l:int = values.length;
    var n:int = l * 0.5;
    n -= n % 2;
    for (var a:int = 0; a < n; a++) {
        var b:int = (l - a) - 2 * ((a + 1) % 2);
        //we cannot use xor because it truncates the decimal value
        //values[a] ^= values[b];
        //values[b] ^= values[a];
        //values[a] ^= values[b];
        //we MUST use a temporary variable instead
        var c:Number = values[b];
        values[b] = values[a];
        values[a] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you XOR'ing doubles??

Comment: I need to switch their values.  XOR works with references (because you are swapping a memory address).  But the behavior is different for primitives apparently.  Hopefully, the additional code provided makes my purpose obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xor-swap operation is not an optimization. It's a pessimization.

It's hard to think to any architecture in which that would be a good idea (four steps each one depending on the completion of the preceding one even assuming read-modify-write memory to memory as atomic... a truly horrible implementation of swap).

The best way to do an exchange between two values in memory is most often a double-read followed by a double-write:

```
reg1 = mem1; reg2 = mem2;
mem1 = reg2; mem2 = reg1;
```

each of those pairs can also be executed in parallel (the two reads are independent, and also the two writes are independent) so the operation can complete in two steps.
Most optimizing compilers are able to recognize the idiomatic three-steps swap

```
{ type temp = x; x = y; y = t; }
```

to generate the two step exhange code for that it this is the best way for the hardware.

That said something "equivalent" for floating point to that bad xor-swap code can be obtained by using inplace subtraction `-=` instead of inplace xor `^=`.

It is however a true exchange only if accuracy problems don't kick in.

Comment: Ah!  This is good to know.  Obviously I am testing my code in debug mode, so I KNOW the compiler will not optimize my temp variable swap.  Perhaps it would if I ran the release build compiler.  For now, I will try doing what you describe.

Comment: changing the memory address read/write got me about 100 milliseconds.  Depending on how the CPU feels.

Comment: if you're testing for speed, never *ever* use a debug compile or even the debug player, the differences can be tenfold and often in rather non intuitive places.

Comment: Yeah, I am beginning to realize that.  Especially looking at other tests people have done online where their results are obviously wrong (like Vector not being as fast as an Array even though that is the whole point of a Vector).  The only explanation is that their debug results do not represent a release build performance.  Unfortunately, this means I have to implement my own debug messages for non-debug compilation--a small, but unwelcome task.

Answer (score 1):

`^=` is a bitwise operation, not an integer operation per se (cf., [Adobe's docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_XOR)).  It is helpful to imagine that there is no such thing as ints.

It would actually require a few *more* temporary variables to XOR a Number with a decimal, which won't solve the speed problem.

Though I cannot offer anything to rewrite the swap, I can suggest that you never (*ever!*) declare vars in a for-loop unless you have to.  Ergo:

```
var b:int;
var c:Number;
for (var a:int = 0; a < n; a++) {
  b = (l - a) - 2 * ((a + 1) & 1);
  c = values[b];
  values[b] = values[a];
  values[a] = c;
}
```

Also note that I changed the modulus to [an additive mask](http://www.nicolabortignon.com/as3-bitwise-operations/) using 1, which should be faster.

Beyond that, it may be useful to allow the Vector class to do the sorting, and [write a custom sort method](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/programming_vectors_as3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_5) for your specific use.

Comment: It is my understanding that where you declare a variable in ActionScript is irrelevant.  All variable declarations are compiled as though they were declared at the top of the function block.  Placement is purely a cosmetic decision to aid code readability.  I declare variables in the block they are used for this reason.  Thank you for your advice!

Comment: BTW, changing the modulo with the bitwise and shaved about 400 mils off an otherwise 7 second process.  Thanks again!

Comment: Further note: just to be thorough, I tried moving the variable declarations out of the loop.  I actually *lost* a bit of speed doing that.  Definitely weird.  Again, I am compiling a debug .swf so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Well, just test it in a non-debug version. . . you can have more than one Flash Player installed.  Even if you lose speed, get in the habit of putting vars outside of loops; for your specific case, it may not matter (`int` is an internal structure, and the `Number` is only copying a memory location.  However, there would be an improvement if you have to create a `new` object each time in the loop.)

Comment: Ok, so I used the regular compiler and printed the results to the screen to test this again.  For whatever reason, I consistently get more speed from declaring the vars in the loop rather than outside.  However, it's the difference between ~18400 and ~18500 so it's a minute point.  It's just weird.  I guess I could compare the resultant byte-code...

Comment: Thanks for keeping me informed -- that's good to know.  I guess the AVM is optimized in this sort of situation.  There are times when outside declarations will be much faster, so this is just something to keep in mind.